# Access derived class through pointer

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

What i have:

```
class Item {} ;

class ChristmasItem : public Item
{
private:
string color;

public: get_color() { return color;} 

class Store{
Item* item1;
} ;
```

Now if that Item *item1 is a ChristmasItem I want to check its color.  I tried

```
if (dynamic cast <ChristmasItem*> item1! =NULL) item1->get_color() ;
```

with no success. Could you please give me any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not correctly using `dynamic_cast`. You have to define a variable of the desired type in which you plan to store the cast.

```
ChristmasItem *thisItem = dynamic_cast<ChristmasItem*>(item1);
```

Then:

```
 if (thisItem != nullptr) thisItem->getColor();
```

Please note that run time type information (RTTI) is required for this to work, and must be enabled in some development environments.

Comment: You *can* define the variable directly inside the `if` statement, eg: `if (ChristmasItem *thisItem = dynamic cast<ChristmasItem*>(item1)) thisItem->get_color();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you can. And if you only need the object for the scope of the `for` statement, that would be the preferred way. But it is not required to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many problems in your code, and if you are asking especially on dynamic_cast, then dynamic_cast can be applied only if you have virtual functions.

Comment: More precisely, the base class `Item` must be polymorphic type (i.e. has at least one virtual function) to use runtime-checked `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: so normal Item should also have the color attribute and virtual get_color ();?

Comment: @sadboy  You can (and should) make `Item`'s destructor `virtual`, and then use the solution answered by @MikelF.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is close to accomplishing your goal, it just needs some tweaking.

First, you need to add a virtual method to `Item` in order to use `dynamic_cast`. In this case, a virtual destructor will suffice:

```
class Item {
public:
    virtual ~Item() {}
};
```

Second, change your `dynamic_cast` statement to the following:

```
if (ChristmasItem *item = dynamic cast<ChristmasItem*>(item1))
    item->get_color();
```